# Angular toggle a div in a ngFor loop

Tags: html, css, angular

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <div>Title</div>
  <div class="show-more" (click)="do something">Show more</div>
  <div class="extra-content">
    <p>lorum ipsum bla bla bla</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can you toggle the extra content div by clicking on the show-more div element.
this must be unique for every item in the collection.

So a global variable is not useable because that will trigger all the items in the collection (at the same time).

Comment: Create a new component that contains the HTML content for each `item` and pass `[item]` via `@Input`. That way it can have its own individual open/close variables/state without affecting other `item`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Add a new property `show` in `item`, like below**

`items = items.map(item => ({...item, show: false}))`

then toggle it on click.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <div>Title</div>
  <div class="show-more" (click)="item.show = !item.show">Show more</div>
  <div *ngIf = "item.show" class="extra-content">
    <p>lorum ipsum bla bla bla</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**this will set item show uniquely for every row / item**